# Make a column in multiple files the last based on word in column header

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder with multiple files, and all have a column header named `something_last`. I would like to make any column with `_last` in it, the last column of each dataframe in the folder. Given that the `_last` column is at various indices depending on the df, a solution that doesn't include the key word has not worked for me.

This is what I have:

`df_1`

```
column_1        column_last          column_2           column_3
    a                b                 c                  d
```

`df_2`

```
column_1        column_2          something_last          column_3
    a                b                 c                  d
```

This is what I would like:
`df_1`

```
column_1        column_2          column_3           column_last
    a                c                 d                  b
```

`df_2`

```
column_1        column_2          column_3          something_last
    a                b                 d                  c
```

Comment: HI, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `sorted(k, key=lambda s: '_last' in s)` ?

Comment: @rafaelc yup, it seems that's all OP wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
columns=df.columns.tolist()
columns.append(columns.pop([df.columns.tolist().index(key) for key in df.columns if 'last' in key][0]))
df.reindex(columns=columns)
```

the name containing the last one is deleted and alfinal is added.